# Security advantage of prepared statements over PDO::quote

Tags: mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Does prepared statement provide any security advantage over `PDO::quote` in single use queries?

For example, if I have the following query which will be executed only once, is there any disadvantage compared to the prepared equivalent below?

```
// Using PDO::quote
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `config` WHERE name = {$db->quote($name)} LIMIT 1");

// Using prepared statement
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `config` WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(['name' => $name]);
```

I have read that prepared statement is marginally slower due to the two step execution. Is the initial *preparing* step executed on the database server, or is it handled by the PDO extension?

Comment: `PDO::quote()` also requires a two step execution by the way.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, IIRC, quote() is client-side code, so it won't incur a network round-trip. That's what critics of prepared statements often fret about.

Comment: @RaymondNijland `mysql_real_escape_string` does not require a round trip to the database server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808952/does-every-single-call-to-mysql-real-escape-string-require-another-trip-to-the-d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does prepared statement provide any security advantage over PDO::quote in single use queries?

Yes: it works for numeric parameters as well as strings. `PDO::quote()` only works for strings and dates.

> I have read that prepared statement is marginally slower due to the two step execution.

If it is, the difference is insignificant unless your network is very slow or in need of repair. Don't worry about it unless you operate at a very, very high scale (hint: you don't operate at that scale).

> Is the initial preparing step executed on the database server, or is it handled by the PDO extension?

Either, depending on the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` attribute. If you set this to true, then `prepare()` is a no-op (except for saving the SQL string in a variable), and later when you `execute()`, it interpolates your parameters into the SQL string and executes the query without preparing it.

If `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is false, it does a server-side prepare. The DBMS holds some object in memory to represent the query, and it can't execute that prepared query until you separately send parameter values in the execute call.

Comment: "PDO::quote() only works for strings and dates."  assuming you have set the default charset correctly like the manual says then it's "safe".. "I have read that prepared statement is marginally slower due to the two step execution. " Besides when you use `PDO::quote()` you also use two step execution. ..

Comment: "Either, depending on the PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES attribute. If you set this to true, then prepare() is a no-op" besides using PDO in `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` mode is just as unsafe as using `PDO::qoute()` or `mysqli_real_escape_string()` so i advice nobody into using that mode even if it's faster.

Comment: Using quote or escape_string _is_ safe, if developers do it consistently, 100% of the time. But that's a big ask, and app code written by developers is not necessarily tested well to make sure they escape parameters consistently. The advantage of using emulated prepare is that it makes it easier for developers to do escaping using well-tested code. But yes, I agree using proper server-side prepares is better in general.

Comment: Though sometimes server-side prepare can be a liability if the app developer doesn't deallocate prepared statements properly. It can lead to a resource leak in the DBMS server, based on accumulation of prepared statements.

Comment: @BillKarwin In the above comment, are you referring to use cases where prepared statements are used in long lived processes like `ReactPHP`?

Comment: Yes. If you close your session, all the resources associated with that session are cleaned up. This naturally happens if you use traditional PHP or any other "shared nothing" language based on old-school CGI type architecture. But if you have a long-lived session, the prepared statement handles can accumulate in the server.

Answer (score 3):

taken from the [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php):

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form of the query.